# Unable to provide default textfield value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms, angularjs-forms

I'm not able to pass a default to textfield in an angularjs array

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="rname" ng-model="userInfo.rname" ng-init="userInfo.rname='{{ r.Name }}'">
```

The default value is printing as `{{ r.Name }}` and not the value stored in r.Name

'r' is an array as in `ng-repeat='r in restaurants'`

Comment: Not sure you need interpolation there. Did you try to remove the {{ }} in your ng-init?

Comment: yes it prints: `Name: " r.Name "` . No sucess

Comment: Can't you just set `userInfo.rname` to whatever default value you want in your controller?

Comment: @opticon it's an array, the values are changing for every textfield, since there are multiple in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the {{ }} in your ng-init statement.  Try instead:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="rname" ng-model="userInfo.rname" 
       ng-init="userInfo.rname = r.Name">
```

Assuming that `r.Name` is a valid value.

Comment: still returns udefined

Comment: can you `console.log( r.Name )` from your controller? Without knowing more about how your controller data is structured, it's hard to say what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, I'd do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="userInfo in userArray">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="rname" ng-model="userInfo.rname">
</div>
```

Comment: where to add default value for this textfield?

Comment: The default value will be whatever value is contained in that array object's `rname` property. Do you actually want a default value (actual input in the field) or placeholder text (text that only appears until the input takes focus?)

Comment: Then my code should work, assuming the `rname` field actually contains data. From the looks of it, it's currently undefined. Could you update your question with relevant controller code and your `ng-repeat` definition?